# Join between two tables with same fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

i have these tho tables:

```
FT
id|Rif1|Rif2|CodCli|Data1|Data2
```

and

```
FR
id|Rif1|Rif2|Qta|Price
```

I would like to join results filtering from Codcli using Rif1 and Rif2 from both tables (that contain the same values)
I do this:

```
SELECT FT."Rif1", FR."Rif1", FT."Rif2", FR."Rif2", "Data1", "Data2", "Qta", "Price", "CodCli"
FROM FT, FR
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '653' AND (FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1" AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2");
```

But the result is wrong, I would like all data from table FT related to the filtered Codcli but with in addition the data from table FR joined by Rif1 and Rif2 related fields.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: You have a typo error in your code `(FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1 AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2")` should be `(FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1" AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2")` not sure if its related.

Comment: I know the structure is a mess but i cannot modify it and i have to extract data using this fields :(

Comment: maybe i have to use some INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like all data from table FT related to the filtered Codcli

This sounds like a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT FT."Rif1", FR."Rif1", FT."Rif2", FR."Rif2", 
       "Data1", "Data2", "Qta", "Price", "CodCli"
FROM FT LEFT JOIN
     FR
     ON FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1" AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2"
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '653';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOIN if this works for you:

```
SELECT FT."Rif1", FR."Rif1", FT."Rif2", FR."Rif2", "Data1", "Data2", "Qta", "Price", "CodCli"
FROM FT LEFT JOIN FR ON FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1" AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2" where FT."CodCli" = '653';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case postgresql select data from second table then get all data from first table with your where condition. Thats way you are getting wrong result.
Use `left join`. In this case system gets data from first table with condition then joins second table. So

```
SELECT FT."Rif1", FR."Rif1", FT."Rif2", FR."Rif2", "Data1", "Data2", "Qta", "Price", "CodCli"
FROM FT
LEFT JOIN FR ON FT."Rif1" = FR."Rif1" AND FT."Rif2" = FR."Rif2"
WHERE FT."CodCli" = '653';
```